# Orthogonal projection, unitary space and subspace, conclusions

Tags: linear-algebra

$(x, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ is unitary space, $V\subset X$, $P_V(x)$ denotes orthogonal projection of vector $x$ on subspace $V$.  Then:

**a.** $||P_V(x)||\le ||x||$
**b.** $\langle P_V(x), x-P_V(x)\rangle=0$
**c.** for each $v\in V$ we have $||x-P_V(x)|| \le ||x-v||$

I ask for help with this task. My problem is that I don't exactly understand what does it mean orthogonal projection.  For me it is reset (set to $0s$) $(\dim X - \dim V)$ last coefficient in vector $x\in X$ (we project on $V$).

Can you help me? I know that **a., c.** are true (I know theorems), however I don't understand this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W$ be the orthogonal subspace of $V$, for every $x$, there exists $x_V\in V, x_W\in W$ such that $x=x_V+x_W, p_V(x)=x_V$, $\|x\|^2=\langle x_V+x_W,x_V+x_W\rangle=\|x_V\|^2+\|x_W\|^2\geq \|x_V\|^2=\|p_V(x)\|^2$ since $\langle x_V,x_W\rangle=0$.

$\langle P_V(x),x-P_V(x)\rangle= \langle x_V,x_W\rangle=0$.

For every $v\in V, \|x-v\|^2=\|x_V+x_W-v\|^2=\langle x_V-v+x_W,x_V-v+x_W\rangle$=

$\|x_V-v\|^2+\|x_W\|^2\geq \|x_W\|^2=\|x-P_V(x)\|^2$.

Comment: Can you refer to my intuition about reset last coefficient of vector ? Rest of coefficient leave the same (for me).  I would like to achieve some intuition about these things

Comment: where is that coefficient ?

Comment: I think that if $V=\mathbb{R}^3$, and $X=\mathbb{R}^4$ and we get orthonormal base of $V$ then $P_V([1,2,3,4]) = [1,2,3,0]$

Comment: In this case $W=(0,0,0,x),x\in R$

Comment: I don't understand you, be more precisely please.